# JBDS 11.3.0.GA - Fuse generated project doesn't work

Tags: apache-karaf, jbossfuse, jboss-developer-studio

I'm using JBDS 11.3.0.GA on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I'm generating a Fuse project for Fuse 7.1.0 on standalone Karaf platform, using the camel-spring-cxf-code-first template. The project generates correctly but, trying to run it as described by the ReadMe.txt file fails. For example, after installing the bundle as follows:

```
karaf@root()> install -s mvn:com.mycompany/camel-spring-cxf-code-first/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
Bundle ID: 223
karaf@root()>
```

trying to go to http://localhost:8181/cxf/report/?wsdl (of course, after having replaced in the generated code 9292 by 8181) displays "No service was found." in the browser and shows the following in the log file:

```
16:33:36.209 WARN [XNIO-4 task-1] Can't find the the request for http://localhost:8181/cxf/report/'s Observe
```

meaning that the generated project is not valid.

Kind regards,
Nicolas

Answer (score 0):

The deployment of this kind of projects is not working at the moment - see the following statement in the *Readme.txt* file.

> Note: This project does not currently work. It has some issues. It is based
>   on the archetype.

I raised an issue for developers - https://issues.jboss.org/browse/FUSETOOLS-3177.

Comment: Hi, so what you're saying is that, this feature which is supposed to show and to demonstrate how the Fuse plugin for Eclipse works, shows and demonstrates in fact that the Fuse plugin for Eclipse doesn't work. Right ?

Comment: It is not a problem of the plugin itself. Just one of available templates does not work properly. I raised an issue to fix this template. If you want to see more quickstarts which demonstrate Red Hat Fuse, please visit https://github.com/jboss-fuse/quickstarts